# How to show spellchecker(wrong spelling with underline) in TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my application I have a story line - Forgive user typos in search makes it effortless for the users. So what exactly I want when I type something in TextFormField it should do spellchecker. Is there is any solution for that in flutter? Kindly find the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This feature has landed in Flutter 3.7.  To use it, add this parameter to your EditableText or TextField:
`spellCheckConfiguration: kIsWeb ? null : SpellCheckConfiguration()`.

(The spell check configuration currently seems to break on web)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a spellcheck api service for this like [Bing Spell Check API](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/overview) it will return the mistakes in the text and you can underline them. Here is the respond of your text;

```
{
  "_type": "SpellCheck",
  "flaggedTokens": [
    {
      "offset": 14,
      "token": "Sofyware",
      "type": "UnknownToken",
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "Software",
          "score": 0.9140160264956476
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[here](https://rapidapi.com/collection/grammar-spellcheck-api) is some APIs you can check them out and select which one works for you.

---

And here is a package include english words that you can check if the word inside it; https://pub.dev/packages/list_english_words

Comment: We don't have any simple way. Without any api and all. because api and all it will take time right? App will become slow...And not only that to show underline and all will be difficult right?

Comment: here is a simple way that I added it to my answer.

Comment: can u send me some sample app. Because I want to show underline for that particular wrong word. If it is not there in dictionary it should  show underline.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu have you got any solution for this case?

Comment: @DhavalPatel nop

Answer (score 0):

Create a TextFormField and set its properties. You need to use the autovalidateMode property to enable spellchecking. Set it to AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction to trigger spellchecking when the user interacts with the field.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _textController,
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Type something',
  ),
)
```

,